# Améliorer mon français pour obtenir une maîtrise en droit

Tags: ressources, droit-et-justice

Je voudrais trouver des vidéos pour améliorer mon français (obtenir un niveau universitaire). J'ai besoin d'améliorer mon écriture en particulier. Je compte faire une maîtrise en droit et j'ai peur de ne pas être capable d'écrire à ce niveau. J'ai suivi des cours de français jusqu'à la fin du lycée (cela fait plus de dix ans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonsoir,

Pour ma part, je cherchais à travailler mon anglais et j'ai découvert le site web [Gymglish](http://www.gymglish.fr/) qui propose des leçons adaptées au niveau que l'on a. J'y suis abonné et j'avoue avoir beaucoup apprécié son fonctionnement. Récemment ils ont lancé le même concept mais à destination des étrangers qui souhaitent apprendre le français. Du coup, je me suis dit que ça t'intéresserait peut-être, d'autant plus que tu cherches à t'améliorer à l'écrit.

Je t'invite donc à jeter un coup d'œil au site web [Frantastique](http://www.frantastique.com/) qui pourrait t'intéresser. En revanche je ne saurais te dire les tarifs proposés mais si c'est comme Gymglish, c'est intéressant à mon sens.

Si tu cherches à voir de bonnes vidéos, je pense que Youtube est un bon endroit où tu trouveras beaucoup de vidéos en français. Après tout dépend de ce qui t'intéresse car si le sujet ne te plaît pas, il y a de fortes chances que tu décroches vite, à moins que tu sois très motivé ! :P

Sinon, tu peux t'orienter vers les podcasts sur iTunes où tu retrouveras les radios d'information généraliste en France. Ils parlent de sujets très variés. Je pense à Radio France, Europe1 ou RTL, à toi de voir.

J'espère que ces informations t'aideront. Je reste persuadé que l'usage est la meilleure recette pour bien apprendre une langue. Peut-être as-tu l'occasion de rencontrer des français par chez toi ? Bon courage !

Comment: Je trouve la pluspart des videos sur Youtube ne sont pas avancee

Answer (score 0):

Si vous disposez d'un smartphone, il existe également des applications mobiles telles que "Améliorez votre français" ou en payant le projet voltaire.
Bon courage!